# RDF4J in Android AppInventor

Tags: android, maven, app-inventor, rdf4j

I'm trying to integrate RDF4J library in an AppInventor project. Every time I get the following error:

```
    org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.UnsupportedRDFormatException: Did not recognise RDF format object Turtle (mimeTypes=text/turtle, application/x-turtle; ext=ttl)
08-29 12:27:10.417 30454 30499 W System.err:     at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:285)
08-29 12:27:10.417 30454 30499 W System.err:     at org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.Rio.createWriter(Unknown Source)
```

Even if I use the Maven ServicesResourceTransformer shade plugin to compile my code without losing parsers I get this error.
I read that AppInventor uses Java 6, so I think there is a problem related to Java versions incompatibility. Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks

Comment: Are you writing an App Inventor extension? You might want to ask in the open source development category of the App Inventor community here https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/c/open-source-development/10

Comment: I'm not an Android/App Inventor expert, but RDF4J requires Java 8 at a minimum. So if it's indeed using Java 6, that will likely cause problems.